# Como puedo crear una lista nueva elementos aleatorios sin elementos repetidos en Python

Tags: python, lista

Estoy haciendo un programa que simula un juego de lotería, y no eh podido resolver este problema hasta ahora, por favor alquilen que me ayude. Usar el método sample de random no me ayuda en este caso pues eso se usa ya cuando la lista ah sido creada.Este código es el que eh podido hacer hasta ahora:

```
import random

def llenarVector(): 
lista = []
for i in range(0,7):
    lista = lista + [random.randint(1,45)]
lista = list(set(lista))
return lista

for i in range(0,5):
    print("La lista aleatoria es: ",llenarVector())
```

`

Comment: Hola Bilongas, he marcado la pregunta como duplicado, dado que en esencia es el mismo problema. En tu caso no es una cadena, pero es lo mismo, puedes generar la secuencia con `range`:  `lista = random.sample(range(1, 46), k=7)`. El problema de usar `set`, es que aunque te elimine los duplicados lógicamente puedes acabar con menos de 7 elementos. Si tienes alguna duda comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: Vaya!, no vi tu comentario, ahora mismo lo pruebo :D

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda colega

Comment: De nada, por cierto, no lo he comentado pero si observas se usa `range(1, 46)` y no `range(1, 45)`. Esto se debe a que `random.randint` incluye el elemento final del rango, mientras que `range` no lo hace (por lo que no se incluiría el 45 entre las posibilidades). Un saludo.

Comment: Claro tienes razón, gracias por ayudar aun mas :D